# How to cache NXDOMAIN when no SOA record is returned

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

So we're trying to use the Barracuda RBL (http://barracudacentral.org/rbl) to detect bad IPs as part of our fraud filtering. Unfortunately it appears that our nameservers are not caching the NXDOMAIN for valid IPs for more than a second. We're using BIND, and max-ncache-ttl is set to default. I do notice that as part of the NXDOMAIN no SOA record is returned, yet for a invalid subdomain of Google an SOA record is returned as part of the NXDOMAIN. So is the Barracuda RBL doing it wrong? Any way to force BIND to cache it for a longer period of time, even though an SOA is returned as part of the NXDOMAIN?

```
# dig 1.2.2.4.b.barracudacentral.org

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6 <<>> 1.2.2.4.b.barracudacentral.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 16258
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.2.2.4.b.barracudacentral.org.    IN  A

;; Query time: 58 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.103.2#53(192.168.103.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 12 10:45:29 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48

# dig afa43fsdf.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6 <<>> afa43fsdf.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 56529
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;afa43fsdf.google.com.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     60  IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 204305905 900 900 1800 60

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.103.2#53(192.168.103.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 12 10:46:52 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd:
```

88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that service is sending incomplete responses.
An `NXDOMAIN` (or `NODATA`) response should always include the relevant `SOA` record in the `AUTHORITY` section.

The negative cache time is defined to be [MIN(SOA TTL, SOA.MINIMUM)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308#section-5), where both components rely on the `SOA` record being part of the response.

Comment: Thanks, kinda what I figured, but good to have it confirmed. Any way to force BIND (or Linux OS DNS cache) to cache the NXDOMAIN for a minimum time we set?

Comment: Afaik BIND includes no option to force a higher TTL than the zone owner indicates (only the other way around, which makes sense from a compliance perspective). Some other recursive resolvers do, though (eg unbound's [`cache-min-ttl`](https://www.unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html) option).

Comment: Thanks, perhaps we'll look into Unbound. Hadn't heard of that one.